# TTY doesn't go up

Tags: debian, display, tty

When I'm on a TTY (Debian 12 amd64), entering with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for example, after the 25th line, the screen doesn't update sending the other lines up, this way I can't see what is typed or displayed after that line.

How can I update lines as they are typed and displayed on the TTY?

In a terminal emulator, on the desktop, it's ok, the lines update and go up.